# Flutter Blue read characteristic issue

Tags: flutter

I used flutter blue plugin to read characteristics values, but the reading process always gives an error

```
readCharacteristics() {
    device.discoverServices().then((services) {
      services.forEach((_service) {
        _service.characteristics.forEach((c) {
          device.readCharacteristic(c).then((value) {
            print('value is $value');
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

I expected the output to be the characteristics values, but i got this error ==> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(read_characteristic_error, unknown reason, may occur if readCharacteristic was called before last read finished., null)

Comment: Did you tried to follow the library example? https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Answer (score 0):

`device.readCharacteristic(c).then((value)` is an async call and the result is handled in the future. This can create a situation where you call a couple reads when none of them have returned, the reads need to happen synchronously. Try replacing all the `forEach` with `for (final x in iterable)`, then you can `await` on each `readCharacteristic` so that they happen synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Do not perform read and writes simultaneously. I used mutex concept to resolve this.
I suggest to perform only single write or read at any point of time. Synchronize read and write operations

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that:

```dart
if(isReading == false){
 isReading = true;
 await bluetoothCharacteristic.read();
 isReading = false;
}
```

it will prevent you to read simultaneously