# Control ESP32 via Flutter BLE

Tags: flutter, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using this library (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue/example) to control my ESP32 (Arduino). I have two buttons that work perfectly, one to turn off the led and one to turn on the led. My problem is that I want to receive data that the arduino sends (notify). I don’t know how to do it.

Comment: Reading is different from receiving notifications. Could you [edit] your question and add the code for your esp32?

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647937/flutter-blue-read-characteristic-issue) recommends how to avoid simultaneous reads & writes

Answer (score 0):

Try using [String.fromCharCodes](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/String.fromCharCodes.html) to convert the received data ([57, 56, 46, 57, 54]) to 98.96.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this utf8 char table: https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/02572bcf-76c4-420a-90ac-65a0c8c71eae/iso-8859-5-php-orange.png

You are receiving Uint8List. Decode that data into string then parse it in double.
Try this:

```
String decodedData = utf8.decode(receivedData);
```

where receivedData -> Uint8List

Now in decodedData you will get the required string that you can parse into other data types.